# Problem with Java and X11 DISPLAY on Ubuntu

Tags: java, swing, ubuntu, x11

I am running on a machine with Ubuntu 22.04 (with a dual boot with Windows) and whenever I try to run a graphical Java application, I run into the following error: "No X11 DISPLAY variable was set"

I looked for this error and I understand that Java cannot access the display variable to run graphical application. What I don't understand is why it does not access it. Indeed if I open a terminal and echo display, it works

```
$ echo $DISPLAY
:0.0
```

If I run xeyes, it also works. But if I run my java application, I get

```
Exception in thread "main" java.awt.HeadlessException:
No X11 DISPLAY variable was set,
or no headful library support was found,
but this program performed an operation which requires it,

      at java.desktop/java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment.checkHeadless(GraphicsEnvironment.java:166)
      at java.desktop/java.awt.Window.<init>(Window.java:553)
      at java.desktop/java.awt.Frame.<init>(Frame.java:428)
      at java.desktop/java.awt.Frame.<init>(Frame.java:393)
      at java.desktop/javax.swing.JFrame.<init>(JFrame.java:180)
      at Main.main(Main.java:9)
```

Maybe, my java version is "headless", how do I know that? And If so how can I fix it? I get this error, whether I run from the terminal or from Eclipse, all the same. In the terminal, it says my java version is:

```
$ java --version
openjdk 19.0.2 2023-01-17
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 19.0.2+7-Ubuntu-0ubuntu322.04)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 19.0.2+7-Ubuntu-0ubuntu322.04, mixed mode, sharing)
```

By the way, the code I am trying to run is:

```
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Main {

      public static void main(String[] args) {
            JFrame fenetre = new JFrame();
            fenetre.setTitle("Première fenêtre en java");
            fenetre.setBounds(0,0,300,100);
        fenetre.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        JLabel helloWorld = new JLabel("Hello World !");
        JButton bouton = new JButton("Je suis un bouton");
        panel.add(helloWorld);
        panel.add(bouton);
        fenetre.add(panel);
        fenetre.setVisible(true);

      }

}
```

I just do

```
$ javac Main.java
$ java Main
```

And I get the error. I get the same error when trying on Eclipse

Comment: If you have a [openjdk-19-jdk-headless](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=default&section=all&arch=any&keywords=openjdk-19&searchon=names), then the fix would be `sudo apt install openjdk-19-jdk` I guess.

Comment: Thanks! It was the problem indeed. I have no idea why the headless version was installed but now it works

Answer (score 1):

I am posting the fix because it was posted in the comments section: indeed the problem was that the jdk install was "headless". I have no idea how this happened as it is actually not my own machine.

If ever someone has the same problem, the solution for us was to install the non headless version

```
sudo apt install openjdk-19-jdk
```